# Using IF ELSE and LOOP inside a mySql event

Tags: mysql, sql, events

I've never done this before, but why do I keep getting and error when I try to create this event. I'm using HeidiSql to do this. Also, can LOOPS, WHILE, IF ELSE be used in events?

```
BEGIN

DECLARE x TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE y INT;
DECLARE a VARCHAR(50); // Here's where the error is.

SET x = current_timestamp();
insert into checked (stamp) values (x);

SELECT count(stamp) INTO y FROM checked;
        IF y > 10 THEN// It also throws an error here.
            a = 'PASS';
            else
            a = 'FAIL';
        END IF;  

insert into checked (timeCount) values (a);

END
```

Comment: please specified your exact problem.

Comment: @Daniel I'm creating an event. I get /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'PASS';
            else
            a = 'FAIL';
        END IF;  

inser' at line 17 */

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
SET  a = 'PASS';
```

instead of

```
a = 'PASS';
```

Every where you assign value.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Like I said I'm doing an even the first time. I was following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031469/how-to-properly-loop-in-a-stored-function-on-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Use "DELIMITER" to execute entire block in mysql

such as.....

```
DELIMITER

//Your code 

DELIMITER;
```